# My own html report in build summary

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

Previously, I used testlink. This plugin generated a nice table with the test results in the *build summary view.*

Now, I don't use testlink anymore, so this plugin cannot be used. But instead, I want to feed a html report (which I take care of generating) to the *build summary view.*

I tried *HTML Publisher Plugin*, but it makes a link instead of displaying in the *build summary view.*

Is there such a plugin that allows me to specify that a certain .html file from the workspace will be included?

Bonus question: or even a plugin that allows a .html fragment to avoid the use of i-frames?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Summary Display Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Summary+Display+Plugin). It work pretty good.

The configuration is a bit tricky so I'm adding an [example screenshot of my configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOlBT.jpg).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, it doesn't solve my problem. I wan't to display my own report that I generated.

Comment: Sure NP. Just to be on the same page here, This plugin can display any report you create/generate - it just need to be in the format of the plugin.

Comment: I am afraid that is not what I am looking for.